# Custom Error Page not showing with using AJP Proxy with Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy, ajp

I am trying to setup custom 403 and 404 error pages on Apache.

```
Server config is as follows:
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-04-03T13:22:37
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
```

I use Apache for AJP reverse proxy, as below:

```
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /app ajp://localhost:8009/share
    ProxyPassReverse /app ajp://localhost:8009/share
```

My ErrorDocument code is as below:

```
    ErrorDocument 404 /cah-404.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /cah-403.html
```

Now if I go via browser to the above app, like "https://server.xyz/app", I get a message like the below:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /app/ on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at server.xyz Port 443
```

My custom error pages are at /var/www/html
Permission on those pages is 444

Any ideas why this error is happening?
I am trying to access the page from an ISP that is not authorised. So it is fine that Forbidden is showing - but it should show the custom forbidden page.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this using:
https://serverfault.com/questions/266924/apache-reverse-proxy-error-page-when-proxied-server-is-down

The key part of the answer is "You should use a URL to point to your ErrorDocument otherwise if you use a filesystem reference you will get an additional 503 whilst trying to find it."

So now, my errordocument directives look like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://server.xyz/cah-404.html
ErrorDocument 403 http://server.xyz/cah-403.html
```

Comment: Update - this answer did not work too well. It worked on my Macbook in Google Chrome. But did not work in any other browser. Also didn't work on my colleague's Linux box on any browser. Kept giving infinite redirects.