# How to hide sensitive data being revealed to a non Jenkins user

Tags: security, authentication, jenkins, error-handling, account

A non-Jenkins user is presented with the below error in the browser when he tries to access a URI:

```
HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

URI: /contextMenu
STATUS: 403
MESSAGE: HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
SERVLET: Stapler
========================================
Powered by Jetty
========================================
```

How can we hide the above sensitive information from the non-user in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

You can see in [Jetty releases](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-test-harness/releases) the `jetty.version` variable used, so running Jenkins with `-Djetty.version=xxx` would help for 404 pages.

Not so for 403 pages.

Ideally, you would embed your Jenkins in a Tomcat server, where it is [easier to setup custom error pages](https://www.yeahhub.com/set-custom-error-page-apache-tomcat-server/), as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56989982/6309).